# Request API kotlin

Tags: java, api, kotlin, request

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val url = "Some URL"
    doAsync {
        Request(url).run()
        uiThread { longToast("Request performed") }
    }
}
```

My only problem here is an unresolved reference: Request.
Unfortunately, I'm a new Kotlin programmer and I have no idea of where my problem can be.

Comment: You need to import the classes that you use. Put your cursor on `Request` and press Alt-enter to get the IDE to suggest which line to auto-import for you. Are you using Anko? It is deprecated.

Comment: I am using Anko but there is no an auto-import option that would fix this problem. Every one of them underlines that line. I can choose between: [link](https://prnt.sc/xo53mk)

Comment: Since you are new to programming (or just Kotlin? I'm not sure...) I guess you copied the code from somewhere? If true, could you link to that or say, which library you're trying to use. It seems to me like you are lacking a library to make an API request.

Comment: No problem, I'm trying to create the simpliest request from here: [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6994782-android-networking-with-kotlin-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-004). To clarify I did everything what was mentioned before a screen shot with simmilar code to mine.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is no a proper library to import or I just can't write the right code after importing the right one.

Comment: You should pick the last one in that list (okhttp3), since the tutorial you're following is using Retrofit. And ignore what I said about Anko. The tutorial has a note saying they know it's deprecated, and they will remove it later in the tutorial.

Comment: Still I'm stuck here... [LINK](https://ibb.co/f42HM87). Having no idea what is wrong.